# How can I eliminate the "jitter" from my "estimated time remaining" (and ETA) calculation?

Tags: c#, .net, progress

I have an application that, while performing a background task, shows a progress bar with an "estimated time remaining" calculation (eg "5 seconds remaining") and a "estimated time of completion" (eg "complete at 12:59:59"), or as I call it, the ETA.

The algorithm for calculating this ETA basically takes the "rolling average" of progress over time:
1. Each progress event gets added to a queue with the current time.
2. After a certain duration (eg. 10s), items are removed from the queue.
3. The ETA is extrapolated from the first and last items in the queue.
The source code is available if you care: [ETACalculator.cs](https://github.com/scottrippey/Progression/blob/master/Progression/Extras/ETACalculator.cs)

However, there's a **jitter problem**.  As each progress event is added to the calculation, the ETA will be updated slightly.  Let's say that the ETA changes by only `0.1s`.  This small jitter easily causes the ETA to "flutter".  For example, instead of seeing a smooth progression from 5s, 4s, 3s, etc..., I see 5-5-5-4-5-4-5-4-5-4-4-4.

I was thinking of just reducing the updates to 1-per-second, but then the progress bar is less smooth, and also I'd really like "actual" slowdowns to be shown real time.

I'm having trouble coming up with a simple algorithm that reduces this jumpy jitter.  How can I remove the jitter?

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Something else? Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/612/).

Comment: Only update the progress if it's reduced. (i.e. don't change back to 5 if we're currently on 4).

Comment: Calculate the *moving average* instead.  Add all samples and divide by the number of them.  That greatly helps having the sample errors cancel each other out.  Don't store too many of them to avoid having history affect the outcome.  Or bias later samples.

Comment: @Hans: That's why extrapolating from the first and last items does.

Comment: @Oded The progress calculation and ETA is in a library that is independent from WPF & WinForms, and might be used with both; the current application is WPF.  I added a link to [ETACalculator.cs](https://github.com/scottrippey/Progression/blob/master/Progression/Extras/ETACalculator.cs) if you're interested in the actual code.

Comment: @Ani Thank you for the XKCD reference, I'm going to embed that in the project's wiki page!

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett That's a good suggestion, but in this situation, if the progress slows down, I'd like to show the increased estimate.  Your suggestion is on the right track, though.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm pretty sure that my current algorithm is a *moving average* as you describe.  I'd like to improve the algorithm in the future, but either way, the sub-second jitter is still a problem.

Comment: Well, just ignoring good samples you have (the ones in between the first and the last one) is never a good idea.  Obvious, no?  Check the formal definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to calculate ETA of an operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852670/best-way-to-calculate-eta-of-an-operation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Separate the **actual jittery progress** and the **displayed progress** into two separate variables.

Update the jittery progress as you do now.

At a regular (relatively quick) interval, update the displayed progress to *approach* the actual progress.

A simple approach algorithm would be to average the two values

```
display_progress = (display_progress + actual_progress) / 2
```

This will dampen the value to reflect past values and not just the immediate value.

You can also refine the smoothness by using:

```
display_progress = (P) * display_progress + (1.0-P) * actual_progress
```

Where `P` is a constant value between `0.0` and `1.0`.

**Edit:**

This is one of many filters that could be used.  This one is nice in that it doesn't require much bookkeeping.

However, getting **perfect output** is not going to be an option, because the flaw is in your **input**.  The difference between "jitter" and "actual slowdowns" is only observable *after* it has happened.

Comment: Good idea (a first order IIR low-pass filter), but this should be done on the "time remaining" variable, not the "% progress" variable.

Comment: I can see how this will "smooth" the progress, and it might be a good addition to my progress calculation.  But I think this will still suffer from the jitter in the ETA extrapolation.  Even if the jitter is only `0.00001`, that'll show up when the ETA is between `5.00000` and `4.99999`.  Sorry my question didn't make this clear; I'm going to update it.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite clear on your algorithm without seeing code, but when you update your ETA just first check the current ETA and only update it if the new value is lower than the old.

Comment: I updated with a link to [ETACalculator.cs](https://github.com/scottrippey/Progression/blob/master/Progression/Extras/ETACalculator.cs), if you're interested.  However, in my situation, the progress might slow down, in which case I want to display an accurate ETA.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to "debounce": choose the lowest value of the last X values.

Comment: If I chose the lowest, then there will be significant jitter when ever a new "lowest" entry appears.  Same if I choose "highest" or "median".

Comment: @ScottRippey When a new lowest entry appears, that value is used instead. Where is the "significant jitter"? Using the last X values means that the value stays stable for that many samples. Eg with input 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4 and X>=3, my approach will just show 4: no jitter. The only way to still get jitter is if your input is 4, then 5 (or anything > 4) for X samples, then 4, then 5 for X samples, then 4, <repeating>. In that case it will show 4 for X samples, then 5 for 1 sample, then 4 for X samples. If you don't like that jitter, use a larger X. You can't do better with bad input.