# algorithm to calculate ETA of a file downloading session

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Estimating/forecasting download completion time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881652/estimating-forecasting-download-completion-time)

Just curious how does ftp clients calculate estimated time to finish? Does it use any average number over past few minutes' data or any other algorithm to get more accurate time? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881652/estimating-forecasting-download-completion-time