# Formula for Audio Streaming in mobile devices?

Tags: iphone, android, streaming, formula

I wonder what would be a good formula to calculate how many bytes I have to download for smooth playback.

I have the file size before start to download and I can check the network (GPRS,EDGE,UMTS...). I know that there are so many possibilities (network delay, network changes, no network...) I appreciate any good read about it.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good approach: [Smart progress bar ETA computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933242/smart-progress-bar-eta-computation/933269#933269)