# How to calculate downloading time in c#(FTP)

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp

I want to calculate downloading time in my ftp download manager.

I am using these code to download file through ftp.

```
        try
        {
            string DirectoryCreate = localPath;
            if (!Directory.Exists(DirectoryCreate))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryCreate);
            }
            FtpWebRequest requestFileDownload = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://xxxxxx.com);
            requestFileDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            FtpWebResponse responseFileDownload = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDownload.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream();
            FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(localPath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);
            int Length = 2048;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
            int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            }
            responseStream.Close();
            writeStream.Close();
            requestFileDownload = null;
            responseFileDownload = null;
        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {

        }
```

Can anyone please say me what i should change in my code for calculating download time.

There would be great appreciation if someone could help me.

Comment: Do you want to return how long it took at the end?  Or do you want to give some kind of running total to the user to estimate how long is left?

Comment: Related, but w/o a concrete answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/798800/60761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime t1 =  DateTime.Now;
while (bytesRead > 0)
{
    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
}
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan diff = t2 - t1;//you can return diff or display it using its properties ..
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            }
            responseStream.Close();
            writeStream.Close();
            requestFileDownload = null;
            responseFileDownload = null;

        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {

        }

stopwatch.Stop();
stopwatch.Elapsed // this will give you the elapsed time
```

Comment: stopwatch is out of scope on the line you call stop, it starts in the try block but ends after the catch.

Comment: Sure, thanks for correction - the intent was to show how it can be done. Cheers